# Were seat belts used in Star Trek for the first time in Star Trek Beyond?

Tags: star-trek

At one point in *Star Trek Beyond*, everyone fastened their seat belts. At last! Is this the first time in *Star Trek* (TV, movies) that seat belts have been used?  If not, what was the first time?

Comment: as you can see there are two answers, the in-universe timeline, and the out-of-universe timeline.

Comment: I would have bet anything there were airplane style seatbelts on the captain's command chair on the bridge in at least one TOS episode. But can't find any evidence. Maybe it was the Nimbus in Futurama, after all... ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Seat belts feature in a number of *Star Trek* properties that significantly pre-date *Star Trek Beyond*.

**They were seen in a deleted scene from *Star Trek: Nemesis***

[image: Gif showing Picard sitting in a chair surrounded by a few people, he presses a button on the chair's console and a seat belt harness shoots out over his lap and shoulders]

**In *Star Trek Into Darkness***

[image: Gif showing Spock sat in the captain's chair during a turbulent flight, he presses a button of the chair and and updated seat belt harness to Picard's unfolds itself across his lap and shoulders]

**Shuttlecraft also have them in various episodes of TNG**

[image: Riker and Data sit at the controls of the shuttlecraft with Riker turning to look at Deanna who sits behind them. All 3 have the seat belt harness on but they look to be manual not automatic ones]

**The Animated Series (TAS: "Once Upon a Planet") during a *gravity loss scenario*.**

[image: Arex and Gabler sit side by side working away at the controls with white crossed harnesses on. In the background M'Ress can be seen working on a control panel, she doesn't appear to have a harness on]

You can also see that Archer's chair (which looks very suspiciously like Picard's unused prop from Nemesis) has been retro-fitted with slots for shoulder straps in Enterprise, albeit we don't see their use.

[image: Riker sits at the chair looking down as he settles into it, his arms on the arm rests. A circle highlights a silver outlined hole in the back likely to be used for a seat belt/harness]

Comment: I can't see any seatbelts in that _Aenar_ image.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Sorry. Seatbelt *slots*. Since those are where PIcard's seatbelt sprang from, I thought they must serve the same purporse

Comment: @Valorum: Hmm, I never thought of it that way; I'd assumed it was just stylistic (and prop re-use). I can see now why you'd say that but, personally, given that we never saw the prop used in that manner I'm not sure we can use it as an example.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Archer's chair is Picard's chair (they re-used the prop). You're right though that the use wasn't seen in-canon since the seatbelts only appear in a deleted scene.

Comment: @Valorum: Yup, I said it was prop re-use :) I guess my point is that not only was the Nemesis seatbelt scene non-canon, but that prop re-use is out-of-universe so even if the Nemesis scene had been canon, you can't say in canon that it's the same chair (obviously not - it's hundreds of years older!) so it says nothing about the capabilities of Archer's identical-looking chair anyway.

Comment: Darn it!  I forgot about the belts in TAS.  Episode wise they are first, and TMP is 2nd

Comment: I don't see the example of Archer's chair as actually answering the question.  Although I do see some metal over his right shoulder (on the left side of our picture), and understand that is part of a seatbelt assembly, it doesn't look like he's actually using that belt.  Although I do find this to be an interesting find, I'm just pointing out that it doesn't answer the actual question, since the question isn't whether seat belts existed, but whether they got used.

Comment: @TOOGAM - As I've said to Lightness, we see in the deleted scene that the gap was for a seatbelt. That chair (prop) was then recycled into Enterprise. Now you could certainly argue that it's for something else, but I'm at a loss what that something else would be.

Comment: Valorum: Just because the gap was designed to allow a seat belt to extend out of the chair doesn't mean that the crew actually used the belt.  When we talk about seat belts getting used, I don't think we usually mean that the shipyard worker used the belt, by installing the belt into the chair, to make a chair that meets safety specifications.  I believe the term "using the belt" means someone actually wearing it.  So, even if the belt is actually inside that chair and ready to be extended, that fact doesn't mean that the belt actually gets used (by Archer, in this case).

Comment: @TOOGAM - Fair enough. The fact that there's a seatbelt in my car isn't proof that I use it, but I'd certainly cite it as evidence that they exist.

Comment: But if they have seatbelts on, how will they be thrown clear from the exploding consoles? Would their injuries not be *worse* if held close to the overloading panels?

Comment: What about the chair arms in ST:TMP that fold over their legs?  They aren't actual belts, but they serve the same purpose.

Comment: @tango - They've already been mentioned;http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135823/20774

Answer (score 34):

That all depends on your definition of "**Seatbelts**".  The first bridge *seat restraint system* was seen in [*Star Trek: The Motion Picture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture).

On the Captain's chair, the seat arms folded down over the lap during emergencies.

[image: The captain presses a button on the chair's control which causes the arms to move in over the top of the legs locking him in place]

Comment: McCoy's facial expression seems to say: "Uh, where do I sit?"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - At least he found a razor.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the other fine answers, seat belts were used the first time humans achieved warp (*Star Trek: First Contact*):

[image: Shot from within the Phoenix showing Cochrane flying the ship with Riker and La Forge in the back seats, all grimacing. They all wear X shaped harnesses and Rikler also holds onto the side for grip]

Answer (score 10):

In [*ST3: The Search for Spock*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088170/), the crew of the Excelsior use some kind of seat restraint just before they go to trans-warp.

[image: The crew ready for trans-warp by shuffling in their seats and pulling the arm rests in which lock over their legs and body holding them in place]

Answer (score 3):

#No

There were seat belts used in the TNG era as well as in the new, alternate timeline.

- The alternate timeline version of the Enterprise has seat belts that sort of craw or unroll onto your body. There is a scene where someone is knocked out, put into a chair, and then a button is pushed to activate seat belts/safety restraints to avoid injury.

  [image: Gif showing Spock sat in the captain's chair during a turbulent flight, he presses a button of the chair and and updated seat belt harness to Picard's unfolds itself across his lap and shoulders]
- One of the TNG feature films included a scene in which Cpt. Picard (and others) are strapped in use some sort of heavy duty seat belts.

  [image: Picard sits in the captain's chair looking up at Worf who stands besides him; he has a black thick harness on to hold him in the seat]

Answer (score -2):

And there's this from Yesterday's Enterprise. A lap-only belt, it seems.

[image: Frontal view of the full crew ready at their stations, Picard can be seen with a belt across his lap with Riker talking in his ear]

Comment: Are you sure that's not his gun-belt?

Comment: I watched this episode, and those silver things are gun belts. In this alternative timeline, the crew carries weapons all the time due to the active state of war with the Klingons and the possibility of going into battle at any moment.