# Why are Starfleet vessels not fitted with seatbelts or harnesses of some kind?

Tags: star-trek

Simple question, seatbelts. I'm looking to see if it's ever mentioned canonically or not.

I was watching an early episode of TNG last night, giggling at Riker's dance-like twitching as the Enterprise shook, and, as Worf took a less-than-realistic 'safety-dive' toward the deck while almost breaking the set, my partner-in-crime asked me "Why don't they have seatbelts?". I was kind of caught off-guard... why, in all the time I've spent watching Janeway's hair flapping out of its restraints, have I never asked myself this question?

Yes, they have inertial dampers but yes, they fail or, more accurately, are reported "offline" often during hostile encounters and rough rides and I'm left wondering how many of the Alpha Quadrant's finest would have been saved by a simple (yet advanced) chair-harness of some kind? Do they not remember the *"Clunk-click, every trip"* campaign?

In the TV series, they seem to take it for granted that if the inertial dampers go offline, they are at the mercy of their environment, they know they have no kind of restraint other than the gravity plating which is marginally beneficial in that situation. At least after the torturous rag-doll-ing, they know they'll end up back on the floor!

So was it ever mentioned on TV or off? I'd even stretch to non-canon for this. Maybe they came up with some general reason somewhere that will settle my mind a bit.

Edit: There is a question regarding [***when seatbelts/restraints were first used in the ST TV/Movie universe***](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135821/53332). But this doesn't seem to answer *this* question, in fact, it confounds some of my theories because now I realize that they *were* used in certain places but not in other places where they would be equally or even more beneficial. Even if they had the ability to use a seatbelt but *chose not to* would satisfy me.

Comment: Out of universe, it would seem lamer and less dramatic if everyone was strapped in properly.  Without the seat belts it lets everyone fly around the room or act like they are on a sea vessel, which is amusing.

Comment: They have snazzy snazzy belts in the new movies.  Does that count?

Comment: In STTMP they had chairs in which the the arms came together to form a restraint.

Comment: Voting to leave open because pointing out seatbelts in other properties makes the question more relevant, not less.

Comment: If that question had a "Why" at the start, I'd say it's a duplicate. But as it is, it's not. I edited to try to rebut a bit.

Comment: @gowenfawr it's all relevant (I think) it just confuses the in-universe reasoning in my mind.

Comment: @MarkRogers It's extremely entertaining. But people do die! So it's serious! Out of universe, It might just be that entertainment value (i.e. potential for harm) overrides logical reasoning/realism yet again. My brain doesn't like that. I have to invent my own reasoning then :/ If it happens too much I can't enjoy the story.

Comment: In-universe, I can't really think of any situation that would only bump a starship "a little". They would be moving a fairly high rate of speed, and virtually *any* change in direction would produce an acceleration that would kill the crew, strapped in or not, if the inertial dampers failed.

Comment: @chepner Being hit with an energy blast or shock wave? But you can't use that reasoning now anyway because they have seatbelts/restraints in other instances as stated in the question mentioned in the edit.

Comment: @n00dles That's because the set designers don't really understand physics.